# Select rows that are not present in another table on a specified date

Tags: mysql, list, join, unique

There are two tables I am working with (ft_form_1 & ft_field_options).

**ft_form_1**

```
      submission_id  facility_id    admits  reporting_date    timestamp
        1              111A         8       2017-03-30 00:00  2017-03-30 17:50:11
        2              111A         1       2017-03-31 00:00  2017-03-31 17:53:17
        3              222B         3       2017-03-31 00:00  2017-03-31 18:42:20
        4              333C         6       2017-03-31 00:00  2017-03-31 19:27:47
        5              222B         0       2017-04-01 00:00  2017-04-01 18:12:12
        6              333C         4       2017-03-31 00:00  2017-04-01 19:38:25
        7              333C         5       2017-04-01 00:00  2017-04-01 20:31:16
```

**ft_field_options**

```
    list_id option_order    option_value    option_name
    1       4               111A            New York
    1       2               222B            Chicago
    1       1               333C            Boston
    1       3               444D            Miami
```

**I'd like to show all facilities in the ft_field_options table (with a list_id = 1) who did not have a submission with a reporting_date in of 2017-04-01 in the ft_form_1 table.**  Each facility should only appear once.  In actuality I will want to be looking at reporting_dates of 'yesterday'.  Thanks again for helping a mysql newbie

```
    facility_id option_name option_order    
    111A        New York    3
```

Match on ft_form_1.facility_id & ft_field_options.option_value

Comment: Remove Comment.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the primary key - foreign key relationship between 2 tables? No column appears common.

Comment: I'd assume a join on: ft_form_1.facility_id & ft_field_options.option_value

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ft_form_1.facility_id, ft_field_options.option_name, ft_field_options.option_order
FROM ft_form_1
INNER JOIN ft_field_options ON ft_form_1.facility_id = ft_field_options.option_value
WHERE  ft_form_1.facility_id NOT IN (SELECT ft_form_1.facility_id from ft_form_1 WHERE ft_form_1.reporting_date = #04/01/2017#);

Comment: does this help?

Comment: This did not seem to work.  Also I don't see anything about list_id=1.  Thanks!  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5972/3/0

Comment: list_id = 1 can be added to WHERE clause further:                       SELECT DISTINCT ft_form_1.facility_id, ft_field_options.option_name, ft_field_options.option_order
FROM ft_form_1 
INNER JOIN ft_field_options 
ON ft_form_1.facility_id = ft_field_options.option_value
WHERE ft_field_options.list_id = 1 
AND ft_form_1.facility_id Not In (SELECT ft_form_1.facility_id from ft_form_1 WHERE ft_form_1.reporting_date = #04/01/2017#);

Comment: Your solution works, but your date needs to be reformatted.  Please see this link and update your answer.  Thank you for your help!  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1aa78/5/0

Comment: yes, because I did it in MS Access. The format may vary depending upon database you are using. If the solution works, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ft_form_1.facility_id, ft_field_options.option_name, ft_field_options.option_order 
FROM ft_form_1 
INNER JOIN ft_field_options ON ft_form_1.facility_id = ft_field_options.option_value 
WHERE ft_field_options.list_id = 1 AND ft_form_1.facility_id NOT IN (
SELECT ft_form_1.facility_id from ft_form_1 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(ft_form_1.reporting_date,'%m/%d/%Y') = '04/01/2017')